# Refer to Array in Declaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, declaration, definition

I was wondering whether I could refer to the array I am declaring in Javascript in its own declaration...
See code

```
var data = [["foo",23],["bar",data[0][1]+6]];
```

I would like that array to be `["foo",23]["bar",29]`

Thank you!

Comment: you cannot really use `data` in the array (you are creating a  new local variable called `data` at that time. Why not create a variable that contains `var fooArr = ["foo", 23], barArr = ["bar", foo[1]+6], data = [fooArr, barArr];`. More interesting would be why you think that you need this kind of construct

Comment: It's kind of a strange question or bad practical example. I wonder why you would do that since 23 is a hard coded number and 23+6 is 29 you may as well do `var data = [["foo",23]["bar",29]]` if the number 23 comes from a variable (let's say `num`) then you can do `["foo",num]["bar",num+6]` if you have an existing array and need an array from this based on previous value you can use reduce or zip/map

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript engine would first parse the array initializer, it won’t find any definitions for “data” and will throw an error. So, it wouldn’t work.

Comment: To clarify: an error will be thrown, because `data` will be `undefined` at that point and no property `0` can exist on it. It won’t throw an error merely because `data` doesn’t exist (`var data;` is hoisted), but something like `let` or `const` will, because of that.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work as your referring to a variable that was not created yet. At this point data it still undefined. So you need first finish the declaration statement and then refer to the variable.